What is 「一段飛ぶします」？

いや、今日は一段飛ぶしますね(YouTube clip)

「飛ぶする」 doesn't make much sense to me. I'd have an easier time if it were 「一段飛び」. What is this construction? Am I hearing it right?

The sentence is "いや、今日は一段と蒸しますね。もう喉カラカラですよ。". The speaker is commenting on the weather.
I think the confusion comes from the fact that the speaker had weakened pitch accent for half a second there. The む in いちだんと [0] むします [3] remained high even after a morpheme boundary and sounded even higher in pitch than the と of 一段と which had a lowered pitch due to terracing.
